# $\log_{4}(6)=a$ and $\log_{4}(5)=b$. Use the change of base formula along with properties of logarithms to rewrite the following in terms of a and b.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The two problems are:

$\log_{5}(4)$ which I was able to solve here is my work:

\begin{align}
\log_4(5) &= b \\
\log_5(4) &= \frac{\log_4(4)}{\log_4(5)} \\
\frac{\log_4(4)}{b} &= \frac{1}{b}
\end{align}

$\log_{5}(6/5)$ which I am stuck at, after applying change of base formula I end up with
$\log_{6/5}(6/5)÷\log_{6/5}(5)$.
I don’t understand where to go from here, since it doesn’t line up with the given a and b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following identities (carefully look at the base and the arguments of the $\log$):

They hold for all $c, m, n > 1$

1. $\log_c(m/n)= \log_c m -\log_c n$
2. $\log_mn= \dfrac{\log_c n}{\log_c m}$
3. $\log_c c = 1 $

With these you should be able to solve.

> Essentially, 
>  $\log_5(6/5) = \log_5(6) - \log_5(5) = a/b -1$ 
>  since $\log_56=\dfrac{\log_4 6}{\log_4 5} = \dfrac{a}{b} $

Answer (score 0):

Following whoisit's answer, in particular choose your favourite number, say $m = 7$. Then, *any* logarithm $\log_a(b)$ can be written in this base, namely

$$
\log_a(b) = \frac{\log_m(b)}{\log_m(a)}
$$

From here, I will omit $\log_m$ and just write $\log$. So in your case, you have $a = \frac{\log(6)}{\log(4)}$ and $b = \frac{\log(5)}{\log(4)}$. You want to find $\frac{\log(6 / 5)}{\log(5)} = \frac{\log(6) - \log(5)}{\log(5)}$. Now continue :)